# Change Spaces to Dashes?

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm using this shortcode function to make flag icons. When you do [flag name="United States"], it outputs United States.gif and "United States" in the alt and title tags. However, I was wondering if there is a way for the URL part of the code to take "United States" and turn it into "United-States.gif" since "United States.gif" doesn't validate. Thank you!

```
    function cwc_flag($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "name" => '',
    ), $atts));
    return '<img src="/images/flags/'.$name.'.gif" alt="'.$name.'" title="'.$name.'" class="flag tooltip" />';
}
add_shortcode("flag", "cwc_flag");
```

Comment: You are writing riddles :) Where do the flags come from? Are they attachments? Or are they uploaded with a theme or a plugin? And where is this function from? From a plugin? A theme? Please file an [edit] and fill the blanks so we can help you getting around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace( ' ', '-', $name )
```

In your code, this would translate to:

```
return '<img src="/images/flags/' . str_replace( ' ', '-', $name ) .  '.gif" alt="' . $name  .'" title="' . $name . '" class="flag tooltip" />';
```

Comment: Thanks! Only problem is that it changes everything, including the alt and title tags, to the dashed name. Is there a way to just target the "name" that's in the filename part?

Comment: Yes, there is, by including that in just the `src`-part; I've updated my answer.